# Preserving whitespace in XQuery HTML output

Tags: html, formatting, xquery

When I run galax-run a.xq, where a.xq is

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
{
    for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
    return <li>{data($x/title)}</li>
}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

the output is all on one line. How do I keep the formatting (new lines and other white spaces) as in a.xq?

Comment: This heavily depends on your XQuery engine. Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using galax. I also tried saxonb-xquery, which has better output.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about "[Boundary Whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-whitespace)", which is either stripped or preserved, with an implementation defined default behaviour. You can however override the default by using a boundary-space declaration. For preserving boundary whitespace, use

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
```

in the query prolog. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-boundary-space-decls for details.

Note that this governs the layout of constructed nodes. Their external appearance may also be affected by serialization settings. The serializer may have an option to re-introduce boundary space, even if it was stripped at construction time. You would have to consult implementation-specific documentation to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out xmllint --format a.xml will print a neatly formatted version of a.xml. That was all I needed. You can also pipe to xmllint, like this:

```
galax-run a.xq | xmllint --format -
```